# html web does not recognize .css file

Tags: html, css

i recently started coding some html&css files. i did a little web page with youtube video in it 
and some design in the css file, however the .html file does not recognize that i use .css file, it gives me 404 error (failed to load data)
important to mention that the .css file is **in** the same directory as html file.

Here what i tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='C:\Users\user\Desktop\website\templates\style.css'>
        <body>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/doesntmatter" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

I've tried also just style.css and more that didnt work

Comment: Use relative path instead of an absolute path. eg: `./templates/style.css`

Comment: I've tried that but it doesnt work for some reason ..

Comment: If the css file is in the same directory as the html file, the path would be simply `href='style.css'`

Comment: It would help if you added a document three

Answer (score 1):

First of all the structure on your file is wrong. The body tag shouldn't be nested in the head. But i assume this is not the reason for bad response code. The problem why you can't embed the video is not with the css file it is the src attribute of the iframe tag. Try putting embed/ after https://www.youtube.com . Your link should be https://www.youtube.com/embed/doesntmatter You can find more [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters). And for the css file (if you get 404 in the network section of the browser console) you can always use [relative path](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double quotes as you have in the rest of your code?

```
           <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\user\Desktop\website\templates\style.css">
</head>    
    <body>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/doesntmatter" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </body>
        </html>
```

Also be sure to close your HEAD tag BEFORE opening BODY

Comment: Why down rate me?
I am 100% correct that HTML tags cannot overlap, one cannot open then another open and the first close one close in the middle of the second tag being opened and closed.